# ObjectIds won't add to the rankId array

Tags: node.js

i'm trying to add a array of ranks into my Ladder Model and then after create a Game Object with the created ObjectIds from the Ladder model however the `rankIds` aray keep returning `[]` even though if i inside `ladder.save` log `rank.id` and it return the objectId

**Code**

```
router.post('/:name/:ranks', function(req, res, next) {

  var rankIds = [];
  var params = req.params;
  var ranks = params.ranks.split(',');


  for (var i in ranks) {
    var ladder = new Ladder({
      name: ranks[i]

    });

    ladder.save(function(err, rank) {
      rankIds.push(rank.id);
    });
  }

  console.log(rankIds);

  var game = new Game({
    name: params.name,
    ranks: rankIds

  });

  game.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.json({ message: 'Game created!' });
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the `for..in` loop and calling db save asynchronous function. But executing the `console.log` and `game.save` before the asynchronous operation completes. You should handle it.

Also, its better to use `for` loop (or) `foreach` for array instead of `for..in`.

I have modified the code to make sure `console.log` and `game.save` will be executed after all the asynchronous operations completed. I have used a `vannilaJS` here instead of other asynchronous & promise modules such as [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/), [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) etc which you should consider.

But still worth looking at the below `vannilaJS` code which should be functional.

```
router.post('/:name/:ranks', function(req, res, next) {

  var rankIds = [];
  var errors = [];
  var params = req.params;
  var ranks = params.ranks.split(',');


  for (var i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
    var ladder = new Ladder({
      name: ranks[i]    
    });

    ladder.save(function(err, rank) {
      if(err) {
         errors.push(err);
      } else {
         rankIds.push(rank.id); // Check: if it's a mongodb update then it could be '_id' instead of 'id'
      }

      saveGame();
    });
  }

  var saveGame = function() {
     if(rankIds.length + errors.length === ranks.length) {
        console.log(rankIds);

        var game = new Game({
           name: params.name,
           ranks: rankIds    
        });

        game.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            res.send(err);
          } else {
            res.json({ message: 'Game created!' });
          }
        });
     }    
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
var arr = [];

var save = (callback) => {
  var id = "id";
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback(null, id);
  }, 2000);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  save(function (err, id) {
    arr.push(id);
  });
}

console.log(arr); // Print: []

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log(arr); // Print: [ 'id', 'id', 'id', 'id', 'id' ]
}, 10000);
```

The `save()`function take some seconds to finish, so the first `console.log(arr)` would run before the `for` loop finish (or before any of `save()` function has finished). So, the `arr` is still empty.

But in the second `console.log`, ran after that 10 seconds, it will print out the value of `arr` with 5 values pushed in.

This is simply asynchronous in node js.